# Python : find substring with regex in files

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to find some pattern in my source files with python. This is what i code :

```
import os
import re

data=[]
pattern = re.compile('LocalizedString(.*)')

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if '.m' in filename:
            with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename),'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    matchObj = pattern.findall(line)
                    if matchObj:
                        for match in matchObj:
                            print "match : ", match

    if '.git' in dirnames:
        dirnames.remove('.git')

    if '.svn' in dirnames:
        dirnames.remove('.svn')
```

I want to get all the parameter of `LocalizedString()` call within source code, for example :
in source code :

```
[_deleteButton setTitle:LocalizedString(@"Delete my Account") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I want to get `@"Delete my Account"`, but I got this :

```
match :  (@"Delete my Account") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Are there going to be instances where `)` might be in parameter ?

Comment: Well, iOS code parsing might not be a good fit for a regex. Only for some specific contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using brackets to create a group in your pattern. But you need to specify the start and the end of the statement. Use escaped brackets for that:

```
LocalizedString\((.*)\)
```

Check it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bH4nL2/2).

Comment: What if there is another pair of parentheses after the `LocalizedString()`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It shouldn't matter, because the `.*` matches everything to the last occurrence of the next statement. Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/bH4nL2/3

Comment: I think Wiktor's use case is something like this: `[_deleteButton setTitle:LocalizedString(@"Delete my Account") forState:UIControlStateNormal] ();`

Comment: Well regex is not suitable for this case because it can't "count" the parenthesis.

Comment: @cansik @Adib @Wiktor, I think this is most suitable for me for now, i don't have any lines with `()` after `LocalizedString()`, thank you

Comment: Good, but if you want to match those string literals correctly, use `r'\bLocalizedString\((@"[^"]*(?:\\.[^"]*)*")\)'`